# Rx ItemSelected doing action depend on how much action triggered

Tags: ios, swift3, tableview, rx-swift

I wanna ask about RxSwift. 
I got a problem when i want to use tableView delegate function with RxSwift 
I don't know the source of the problem .. 
The problem is when I do select on a cell with rx.ItemSelected , I got the cell position and event triggered with well at the first time.
The event that i do is pushViewController and then when I pressed back to previous view. After that, i tap again on the same cell .. the cell will triggered twice and if we do the same thing, it'll triggered like incremental from 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> n+1  
Is there any way to fix this ? 
Here's my partial of my code :

```
root.tableView.rx.itemSelected.subscribe(onNext: { index in
    switch index.row :
    case 0 :
    DSource.navbar?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
    case 1:
    Source.navbar?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
    default :
    break

}
```

Comment: In which method is this code? Is there a `disposeBag`?  It seems like the subscription is being created every time your `ViewController` appears.

Answer (score 1):

Add disposableBag to remove the subscription.

```
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()

        root.tableView.rx.itemSelected.subscribe(onNext: { index in
            switch index.row
            case 0: DSource.navbar?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
            case 1: Source.navbar?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
            default :  break
        }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: It didn't fix the problem